# Focus issue of cursor on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I have the following code to autochange background images.

```
function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 3) currentBackground = 0;

    $('body').fadeOut(0, function() {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('body').fadeIn(0);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000);
```

I have a simple form in the front. In internet explorer, this form focus seems to go each time the image changes but works well in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `fadeOut` animates opacity down to 0 *and then sets `display: none`*.

I think Internet Explorer takes focus away from the form when its inside a `display: none` container.

You could try using `animate()` instead:

```
$('body').animate({ opacity: 0}, 0, function() {
    $('body').css({
        'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
    });
    $('body').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
});
```

One question: you're using instant transitions (passing a duration of 0), so why are you calling fadeIn/fadeOut? (it looks like the `css()` call would be enough on its own)